# round exponentially small number with .toFixed()

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I round an *exponentially small number* like this:

`2.4451778232910804e-26.toFixed(4) => 2.4452e-26`

In docs, using `.toFixed()` is going to give me every time `0`. Is there a special function for `exponentially small number`? I would rather not modify `Number.prototype.toFixed()`.

Comment: https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum

Comment: The number in your example appears to be an exponentially small number that's not actually negative => 0.000( x26)000244517... and so would definitely return as 0 with any form of rounding I think whether it is negative or positive. http://www.2ality.com/2012/03/displaying-numbers.html What is the situation where this is causing a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already wrote, `toFixed` isn't precise enough, as it only allows "only" up to 20 decimal places. Multiply + Dividing won't work as well, as the division might give you an inaccurate longer number again. But `toPrecision(<amount-of-precision>)` might help.

edit: If you want 4 decimal places, you need pass 5 as parameter (as the numbers before the point count as well).

`toPrecision` will give you a String, but you may easily cast it back to a number again, if needed. e.g. `Number(someNumberAsString)`

```js
var someNumber = 2.4451778232910804e-26;
console.log(someNumber);
console.log(someNumber.toPrecision(8));
```

Comment: *Technically*, 20 is a soft-limit: "The number of digits to appear after the decimal point; this may be a value between 0 and 20, inclusive, and implementations may optionally support a larger range of values." Mozilla's SpiderMonkey allows up to `100`.

Comment: Indeed, `.toPrecision()` made it possible. Been struggling with `.toFixed()` but apparently it wasnt enough. Thanks for explanation with example, appreciate the answer! (now i see the difference between `toPrecision()` and `toFixed()` x)